# Address class being called from Bank Class

Tags: java, class, mutators

I have 2 classes that extend for each other. I have a mutator method that is calling to the class Address.Java to get the city and state from the class. However the Bank.java class is giving me problems. the specific method giving me problems is

public void setBankAddress(String aCity, String aState)(code is below) I dont know if this makes sense
{

}

Bank.Java

```
public class Bank
{
     private String bankName;
     private int bankID;
     private Address bankAddress;

     public Bank()
     {
         bankName = "?";
         bankID = 0;
         bankAddress = new Address();
     }   

     public String getBankName()
     {
         return bankName;
     }

     public int getBankID()
     {
         return bankID;
     }

     public Address getBankAddress()
     {
         return bankAddress;
     }

     public void setBankName(String aBankName)
     {
         bankName = aBankName;
     }

     public void setBankID(int aBankID)
     {
         bankID = aBankID;
     }

     public void setBankAddress(String aCity, String aState)
     {

     }

     public String toString()
     {
         return "\nBank name:\t\t" + bankName + "\nBank ID:\t\t" + bankID + "\nBank    Address:\t\t" + bankAddress + "\n\n";
      }

}
```

Address. Java

```
public class Address
{
    private String city;
    private String state;

    public Address()
    {
    city = "?";
    state = "?";
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
    return city;
    }

    public String getState()
    {
    return state;
    }

    public void setCity(String aCity)
    {
    city = aCity;
    }

    public void setState(String aState)
    {
    state = aState;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
    return city + "," + state;
    }

}
```

Comment: Call the proper methods of the `Address` class on your `bankAddress` object in the `setBankAddress` method.

Comment: `"However the Bank.java class is giving me problems. the specific method giving me problems is..."` ... usually you'll want to tell us exactly what those "problems" are! Yes, folks will be able to infer the problem with this question, but next time, *please* spell everything out for us so we don't guess wrong. Oh, and 1+ to Sotirios's answer.

Comment: Question rolled back to its original state so that now it again shows its code. Please don't delete information from your question as it makes it completely unhelpful to future users of this site. -1 down vote for this action. If you are doing this to hide the question from your instructors, please don't. I will monitor this site and re-post your question on a site of my own if I must to prevent you from doing this. Please don't make me do this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just not know how to call methods on objects?

```
public void setBankAddress(String aCity, String aState)
{
    bankAddress.setCity(aCity);
    bankAddress.setState(aState);
}
```

`bankAddress` is already initialized in the constructor so you can safely call these methods.

However, it's usually good practice to do that outside such methods and pass the whole object itself

```
Address someAddress = new Address();
someAddress.setCity(aCity);
someAddress.setState(aState);

Bank bank = new Bank();
bank.setBankAddress(someAddress);
...
public void setBankAddress(Address aBankAddress) {
    bankAddress = aBankAddress;
}
```